# Design process on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My process flow is as follows:

1. scrape and download some files
2. Unzip each file into XML file.
3. Convert it from XML to a js array of objects.
4. Then iterate the array and invoke updateDataBase(obj) function.
5. delete the file

I perform this process in local env where the files are downloaded to my project temp folder and there I made all the logic.

now I'm thinking to reduce the usage of my BE when I thought to use AWS lambda function. (the DB is already on aws)

so currently I invoke the lambda function as follows:

1. download some files directly to the s3 bucket

the next steps I don't have enough experience to decide (i learn aws myself in only 1 week)

I think it will be better to store the rar file in s3 bucket and then send api call to my server that will continue steps 2-5 and step 6 is to delete from s3 bucket also.

but I wonder if there is a better way.

its not a professional project and I want to stay in the free tier
currently, the lambda function time is about 30 sec and the max memory size is 80mb (most of the time is 10 sec and 30 MB)

the size of rar file is max 2 mb when the unrar file is around 20-100mb

Could u suggest me a better process?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestions for you.

- Utilize "/tmp" on the lambda function

> > You can configure each Lambda function with its own ephemeral storage between 512MB and 10,240MB, in 1MB increments. The ephemeral
> > storage is available in each function’s /tmp directory.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

you can download the file into "/tmp" local file path which is a local path for lambda functions to use temporarily. Any files downloaded will be deleted automatically when the lambda function finishes AND the environment underneath is terminated.

- Make 2 lambda functions and divide your process

Make one lambda function to download one or more **unzipped** files to s3. Then make a lambda function that gets triggered automatically when a new file gets inserted in a specific S3 Bucket, which you decide on and create solely for this purpose. The second lambda will read the file and continue from Steps 3 to 5.

P.S.:

> 512 MB of ephemeral storage is available to each Lambda function at no additional cost

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

Comment: I know you hinted at it, but just to be explicit: the Lambda function that uses /tmp will need to remove old files from /tmp to avoid diskspace issues when the execution environment is re-used (aka 'warm start').

Comment: Agreed, can you edit the answer and add your bit.